# Username dialog and async task

Tags: android

Let's consider:

1. My app will display a text dialog (the user should put his/her name). The username will be sent to the server to check whether it is unique. It uses an AsyncTask to communicate with server.
2. I have two paths:

   A. The response from server is OK (the username is unique) so the username dialog shoud disappear. It is easy.

   B. The second case is that a username is not unique. I would like my username dialog to still be displayed on the screen. All the information that was entered previously should remain too. So, I cannot just create a new dialog!

I am not an Android expert so my ideas comes from my general experience therefore my attitude may not be fine.

1. First:

Just don't dismiss a username dialog. If the username is unique I call `dismiss` in `onPostExecute`. I think that I have to pass dialog instance to my async task. I think that the state ( information that I said before) won't be destroyed.

2. Second:

To redraw a username dialog after fail ( in `onPostExecute`). It seems to be poor solution because then I have two different method displaying of username dialog.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a similar thing with a dialog in android. In my case I was checking if a login was correct, if the login was correct then the dialog was closed, otherwise the dialog remained open and an error message was shown.

This sounds what you are trying to achieve and it is not difficult to do! It sounds like you are assuming that your AsyncTask would not be controlled by your dialog acivity, however it can just be placed within the dialog fragment itself.

Dialogs (cutom ones) do not self dismiss, you must tell it when to dismiss (unless the user taps outside or presses back).

Take a look here to get started: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Look under the heading: **Creating a Custom Layout**

**EDIT:**

The below is an example as requested, as you can see the AsyncTask is performed in the same class as the Dialog fragment.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null);

    et_username = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    btn_login = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new login().execute(et_username.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    builder.setView(view);
    return builder.create();
}

private class login extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        DAO dao = new DAO();
        return dao.login(params[0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        try{
            if(result != null){
                //Do something with my result
            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            System.out.println("A JSON exception occurred!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! "howver it can just be placed within the dialog fragment itself.". Can you say more what do you mean?